# How can I update a field based on a substring of another field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I'm trying to run an update statement based on the contents of a For XML PATH field. The SQL is:

```
UPDATE a
SET a. ItemsList =
(select distinct Items + ',' from #tScanRemake b WHERE a.ScanOrderCaseid= b.ScanOrderCaseid FOR XML PATH( '') )
FROM #tScanRemake a

UPDATE a
SET a. IsBridge = 1  Select Count (*) from (Select * From #tScanRemake b WHERE CHARINDEX ('Bridge', ItemsList)> 0 )
FROM #tScanRemake a
```

The 1st portion works great and gives me a ,separated list in the ItemsList field. What I want to do is update a bit field based on a substring in the ItemsList field.

The issue is the substring can occur more than once in the list. I only care if it occurs at all. If the string is found then I want to set the IsBridge field to 1 otherwise set it to 0.

I can't figure out how to search within the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**CASE condition**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766102/i-want-to-use-case-statement-to-update-some-records-in-sql-server-2005) in your `UPDATE` statement

```
UPDATE a
SET a.IsBridge = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX ('Bridge', ItemsList)> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM #tScanRemake a
```

Comment: That was my 1st try, but it errored out when there was more than one occurrence of Bridge. Is there a way to specify just the 1st occurrence of the substring?

Comment: CHARINDEX() returns the starting position of first occurenece of string to be searched... having more than one occurence has no effect..

Comment: That worked. The error was from another update statement further in the proc.