# SQL Server : insert and update with specific condition

Tags: sql, function, sql-server-2008

This is the first table:

```
Table source 
(
     id int,
     accno varchar(50),
     duedate date,
     plafond int,
     customer_name varchar(100),
     bicoll int,
     ccy varchar(5),
     parent_id int
)
```

This is the second table:

```
Table result  
(
    id int,
    accno varchar(50),
    duedate date,
    plafond int,
    customer_name varchar(100),
    bicoll int,
    ccy varchar(5),
    jumlah int
)
```

From those tables, I need to make `INSERT` statement to the first table (source) with theseconditions :

1. if plafond < 1000 then group by ccy with accno = "GRUP1", duedate = null, plafond = SUM(plafond), customer_name = "GRUP1", bicoll = NULL, jumlah = *COUNT THE ROWS THAT HAVE BEEN GROUPED*
2. if plafond >= 1000 and < 5000 group by customer_name and ccy with due_date = max(duedate), plafond = sum(plafond), bicoll = max(bicoll), jumlah = *COUNT THE ROWS THAT HAVE BEEN GROUPED*
3. if plafond >= 5000 do not group so that fields jumlah = 1

How to write this `INSERT` statement?

And the second table has relation between `parent_id` (`source`) and `id` (`result`), so if I want to modify something, I used those relation using `UPDATE` statement.

I am working on an `UPDATE` statement, but what confuses me is the `INSERT` statement with those conditions

Please help me, it has been bothering me for weeks. Thank you

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Thanks, i dont have a sample output, because all i need is INSERT STATEMENT for that table. I will edit my threads

Comment: Then show us how should end the db after the insert, or show us a select of the data you would insert.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have time for a long answer but what you need is a basic SQL SWITCH CASE statement.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766102/i-want-to-use-case-statement-to-update-some-records-in-sql-server-2005) for examples.

Comment: can u give do little code for me based on my thread ? after all i will do it  myself, Thanks