# Update Incentive column based on the current salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE EMPSAL
(
  ID INT ,
  NAME VARCHAR(40),
  SALARY FLOAT,
  INCENTIVES FLOAT  
)

INSERT INTO EMPSAL VALUES (1,'ABHI',500,NULL)
INSERT INTO EMPSAL VALUES (2,'BABY',600,NULL)
INSERT INTO EMPSAL VALUES (3,'CHARAN',3000,NULL)
INSERT INTO EMPSAL VALUES (4,'DHANA',4000,NULL)
INSERT INTO EMPSAL VALUES (5,'EMO',5000,NULL)
INSERT INTO EMPSAL VALUES (6,'FARAN',6000,NULL)
INSERT INTO EMPSAL VALUES (7,'GEO',7000,NULL)
INSERT INTO EMPSAL VALUES (8,'JAHANGEER',8000,NULL)
```

Update Incentive column to (SALARY + 5% OF SALARY) if salary is < 1000.

Update Incentive column to (SALARY + 7% OF SALARY) if salary is < 5000.

Update Incentive column to  SALARY  if salary is above 6000.

I have no clue  how to initiate for this query.

Comment: Look up the docs for `CASE`.

Comment: Here is your example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766102/i-want-to-use-case-statement-to-update-some-records-in-sql-server-2005?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Don't store monetary values as `FLOAT`!  Use `decimal`/`numeric`/`money`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please let me know the disadvantage of using FLOAT while creating EMPSAL and what are the advantage of using Decimal/Numeric/Money .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE EMPSAL
SET INCENTIVES = (CASE WHEN Salary < 1000 then SALARY * 0.05  
                      WHEN Salary < 5000 AND salary >1000 THEN SALARY *  0.07
                      ELSE SALARY 
                      END)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Case` like below:

```
Update EMPSAL
Set Incentive =
Case
    WHEN Salary < 1000 then SALARY * 1.05  
    WHEN Salary < 5000 AND salary >= 1000 THEN SALARY *  1.07
    ELSE SALARY
End
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work within the rules you specified (though not you have a gap if the salary is between 5000 and 6000 where it's undefined:

```
UPDATE EMPSAL
SET INCENTIVES = CASE 
        WHEN SALARY < 1000
            THEN SALARY + (SALARY * 0.05)
        WHEN SALARY BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000
            THEN SALARY + (SALARY * 0.07)
        WHEN SALARY >= 6000
            THEN SALARY
        END
```