# Multiple UPDATE queries

Tags: sql

I have a few tables in my database that I need to update.

Unfortunately, this data has never captured in the past and needs to be done now.

The table I have currently has `NULL` in `COL2` and `COL3`, but they have unique keys in `COL1` (obviously).

The basic layout of the tables is like this

```
ID     desc   dateCreated  wRef    tRef
---------------------------------------
T06    url    1/08/2016    NULL    NULL
T07    url    1/09/2016    NULL    NULL
T04    url    11/10/2016   NULL    NULL
```

The values I'm looking at updating are the `wRef` and the `tRef`. These values are all unique.

I have been using the below code to update each line. I have this duplicated 1000s of times as there are 1000s of IDs to update.

```
UPDATE [production].[dbo].[jobsTable] 
SET [wRef] = '0004-01', [tRef] = 'T00-07' 
WHERE [ID] = 'U19695L'

UPDATE [production].[dbo].[jobsTable] 
SET [wRef] = '0005-01', [tRef] = 'T10-04' 
WHERE [ID] = 'U16129L'

UPDATE [production].[dbo].[jobsTable] 
SET [wRef] = '0010-01', [tRef] = 'T01-06' 
WHERE [ID] = 'U17175L'
```

I'm a SQL newbie - is there an easier or cleaner way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You _could_ write a single update with a big ugly `CASE` expression, but I would leave your code as is.

Comment: You can check this [case-when-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766102/i-want-to-use-case-statement-to-update-some-records-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: What's the source for these statements? Do you have a CSV file with the source data in, or something similar? Based on what you've posted there's no better solution. Looking at where the data comes from might suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using [**SQL CASE**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) for you

```
UPDATE
[production].[dbo].[jobsTable]
SET 
    [wRef] =          
          CASE  
            WHEN [ID] = 'U19695L' THEN '0004-01' 
            WHEN [ID] = 'U16129L' THEN '0005-01'
            WHEN [ID] = 'U17175L'  THEN '0010-01'
            ELSE [wRef]
          END ,
    [tRef] = 
           CASE  
                    WHEN [ID] = 'U19695L' THEN 'T00-07'
                    WHEN [ID] = 'U16129L' THEN 'T10-04'
                    WHEN [ID] = 'U17175L'  THEN 'T01-06'
                    ELSE [tRef]
           END
WHERE [ID] IN( 'U17175L','U16129L','U17175L' )
```

Comment: Might work for three rows - but imagine having hundreds, thousands or even more .... gets extremely unwieldy very quickly.

Comment: @marc_s Agree with you,so if there are massive records,so it would be better to use a temp table to store it,as seanb's answer

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd create either a temporary table, or a standard table, with the relevant data you want updated, then do a single update statement. It's a lot cleaner/easier to manage, and the single update probably performs much faster as well.

For example - using a temporary table with the data to be updated:

```
CREATE TABLE #jobsUpdates (ID nvarchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, wRef nvarchar(10), tRef nvarchar(10));

INSERT INTO #jobsUpdates (ID, wRef, tRef) VALUES
('U19695L', '0004-01', 'T00-07'),
('U16129L', '0005-01', 'T10-04'),
('U17175L', '0010-01', 'T01-06');

UPDATE  jT
SET     [wRef] = jU.[wRef], 
        [tRef] = jU.[tRef]
FROM    [production].[dbo].[jobsTable] jT
        INNER JOIN #jobsUpdates jU ON jT.ID = jU.Id
```

It's even simpler if you just have the data already in a table you can access and edit data directly (for example - create the table, copy-and-paste in the data from Excel, then do the one update statement joining jobsTable with the source data).